# smbclient throwing error NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER while copying large files from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, samba, smbclient

We are trying to copy files from linux system to windows and vice versa using smbclient. The files are successfully copied using mget from Windows to Linux, however, we are getting below error while moving files from Linux to Windows.The files are created at the destination with 0 Kb i.e. no data.
Can somebody please help?

cli_push returned NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

putting file  as  (25960.3 kb/s) (average 25960.9 kb/s)

Comment: Sometimes this is caused by a SMB protocol mismatch. Could you add `-m SMB3` to the `smbclient` command line and retry?

Comment: Yes, we tried with SMB2 and it worked. Apologies for late update.

Comment: Ok, nice, I'll add this as an answer then so you may accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be caused by an SMB protocol mismatch. You can specify the SMB protocol version with the `-m` option to the `smbclient` command, e.g. `-m SMB3`.

Comment: didn't work for me. Connection to a QNAP SMB3 service

Comment: @theking2 please post smbclient debug information (`-d` switch) and check for clues in the Samba logs on the QNAP device. Try incrementally increasing the debug log verbosity to catch the error.